# How to sent windows key for google cloud platform as an JSON?

Tags: javascript, json, google-cloud-platform

I need to attach the encoded key to the modulus in for windows set metadata rest call to get a user validated for login.

So the format which google expects is:

```
{
  "fingerprint": string,
  "items": [
  {
    "key": string,
    "value": string
  }
  ],
  "kind": string
}
```

So when you are sending data to google they want in this format.

```
{
  "fingerprint": "sfasdfasdfFSN7AuU=",
  "items": [
  {
    "key": "windows-keys",
    "value": "{\"userName\": \"user\",
    \"modulus\": \"somekey\",
    \"exponent\": \"AQAB\",
    \"email\": \"samleemail\",
    \"expireOn\": \"2019-04-14T01:37:19Z\"
   }"
  }
  ]
}
```

It will also accept if I send the same JSON in this below format but will not perform any action in there:

```
{
  "fingerprint": "asfasd",
  "items": [
  {
    "key": "windows-keys",
    "value": 
    {
      "userName": "user",
      "modulus": "IEFBQUFCM056YUMxeWM",
      "exponent": "AQAB",
      "email": "somemailt",
      "expiresOn": "2019\"04-14T01:37:19Z" 
    }
  }
  ]
}
```

Does any one knows a solution for this or faced this issue?
[Google Doc link](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/rest/v1/instances/setMetadata?authuser=1)

Comment: Please edit your question and remove the pictures and replace with the actual text. Your style prevents people searching for questions like yours from finding any information. Also in time these picture links may become invalid redering your question useless.

Answer (score 1):

In the format definition you're providing, it mentions that the `value` property of every item in the `items` array should be a string, and if you look closely, the "correct" example you provide sets `value` as a string`

```
  {
    "key": "windows-keys",
    "value": "{\"userName\": \"user\",
    \"modulus\": \"somekey\",
    \"exponent\": \"AQAB\",
    \"email\": \"samleemail\",
    \"expireOn\": \"2019-04-14T01:37:19Z\"
   }"
  }
```

However, in your second example, you're setting `value` as an object, so it's not in the expected format, the correct version should look something like this:

```
{
  "fingerprint": "asfasd",
  "items": [
  {
    "key": "windows-keys",
    "value": "{\"userName\": \"user\",
      \"modulus\": \"IEFBQUFCM056YUMxeWM\",
      \"exponent\": \"AQAB\",
      \"email\": \"somemailt\",
      \"expiresOn\": \"2019-04-14T01:37:19Z\" 
    }"
  }
  ]
}
```

That should make it at least accept your request, you might need to fill the email with a correct one and check out whether if it's "expireOn" or "expiresOn" as your examples use both

Comment: Thanks for the response, if you put those extra "" in the code the whole otbjec gets messed up. The issue is when you start putting those "" it will require / inside all value pair to make it correct, which is basically makes it as a wrong json. And yes it's "expireOn" thanks for that.